# How to replace ByteArray elements with modified in hex ASCII symbols?

Tags: c++, string, qt, ascii

I have a problem with QByteArray functions.
My intention is to write the function which will edit the QByteArray i.e:
Input: "1W34567"
Function adds 0x80 to 2nd char - W.
It should replace W(0x57 in ASCII) with ×(0xD7 in ASCII).
I try to solve this problem with following function:

```
void MainWindow::msgModify(QByteArray& ba)
{
    QByteArray t1,t2;
    t1 = ba.toHex();
    int b1 = t1.mid(2,2).toInt(&OK, 16);
    b1+=0x80;
    t2 = QByteArray::number(b1);
    t2 = t2.toHex();
    qDebug() << t1; //Here output is "31573334353637" - correct
    t1 = QByteArray::fromHex(t1);
    qDebug() << t1; //I check if it will give me orginal msg, output is "1W34567" - correct
    qDebug() << b1; //215 decimal - it's correct 
    qDebug() << t2; //"323135" I expect the symbol which has index 215 decimal in ASCII table but I 
                    //got this - why? 
}
```

Comment: [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is really a *seven* bit encoding scheme. Any values above `127` are unspecified in ASCII.

Comment: And as for your problem, what you seems to want is simply `t2.append(b1);`. That will add the value of `b1` to the byte array. When you print it, it will be printed as whatever character that value represents with the current character set (and probably nothing at all if the output console is expecting UTF-8 encoded characters).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved my problem:

```
void MainWindow::msgModify(QByteArray& ba)
   {
    QByteArray hexBa = ba.toHex();
    int t = hexBa.mid(2,2).toInt(&OK,16) + 0x80;
    QByteArray c;
    hexBa.replace(2,2, c.setNum(t,16));
    ba = QByteArray::fromHex(hexBa);

   }
```

I wanted that function to only modify 2nd character by adding 0x80 in hex format, ie.
Input:
ascii: "123456" -> hex: 3132333435
Output: 
ascii: "1²3456" -> hex: 31B2333435

Of course console will encode it like "1\xB2""3456", but it doesn't metter, it turned out that hex format is most important in my case.